# Error Programmatically Converting Set DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, type-conversion

I have a method below to actually get the `count` from a table named `AuditActivity` whereby it takes the starting time of today and end time of today, 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 respectively and another condition. A `datetime` range.

For example, today's date 26/07/17, I want to specify in the `where` condition for the `DateTimeActivity` to take `count` only when it is `between` 26/07/17 00:00:00 AND 26/07/17 23:59:59.

I know what I'm coding is actually wrong but I just seem to not be able to get it right.

I'm currently converting `nvarchar` to `datetime` which is wrong..

Extra information: `datatype` for DateTimeActivity is `datetime` in my `database`

And an example of a value of the field as mentioned right above: '26/07/2017 22:43:06'

```
//Wrong
//Get Number of Logins today from AuditActivity
public int countLoginsToday()
{
    int count = 0;

    StringBuilder sqlCmd = new StringBuilder();
    sqlCmd.AppendLine("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AuditActivity WHERE DateTimeActivity BETWEEN @getStartOfDay AND @getEndOfDay AND ActivityType = @getType");

    //Date Today
    String todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();

    //Time Start
    String timeStart = "00:00:00";

    //Time End
    String timeEnd = "23:59:59";

    try
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionStr);

        myConn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.ToString(), myConn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getStartOfDay", Convert.ToDateTime(todayDate + " " + timeStart));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getEndOfDay", Convert.ToDateTime(todayDate + " " + timeEnd));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getType", "Login");

        count = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        myConn.Close();

        return count;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("AuditNLoggingDAO.getLoginsToday", sqlCmd.ToString(), ex);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Error I'm getting:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I guess the problem is that `todayDate` has the value `"07/26/2017 00:00:00"` and then what you pass to `Convert.ToDateTime()` will end up being `"07/26/2017 00:00:00 00:00:00"`. As others have noted, just use `DateTime` all along don't use strings.

Comment: Agreed. Using one of the proposed answers will fix that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error because

```
todayDate + " " + timeStart
```

would end up as

```
26/07/17 00:00:00 00:00:00
```

Which is not a valid date time to be converted.

You can construct the times as follows

```
//Time Start
var timeStart = DateTime.Today; // 26/07/17 00:00:00

//Time End
var timeEnd = timeStart.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1); // 26/07/17 23:59:59
```

And add them to the query as is

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getStartOfDay", timeStart);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getEndOfDay", timeEnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recipe you can use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getStartOfDay", DateTime.Today);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getEndOfDay", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1));
```

Or you could change your query

```
sqlCmd.AppendLine("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AuditActivity WHERE DateTimeActivity >= @getStartOfDay AND DateTimeActivity < @getEndOfDay AND ActivityType = @getType");
/*....*/

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getStartOfDay", DateTime.Today);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getEndOfDay", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: i read the codes.. would be the same, yours is actually more towards the coding side, like specifying >= / < more or equals/lesser than. appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the date format is incorrect. You only need date portion from DateTime as you are appending the time portion by yourself.

> String todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();

Change above line to:

> String todayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score -2):

A better way would be to create a datetime object for Today with 0 hours and seconds for the start time and then add the hours and minutes later for the end date

```
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getStartOfDay", DateTime.Today);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getEndOfDay", DateTime.Today.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@getType", "Login");
```